# Liqubase: How to trigger all scripts from the folder on changing one of them?

Tags: liquibase

There're three scripts and a `changelog.xml` in a directory. Each script refills one table(delete * from, N lines of inserts):

```
 <databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
  <include file="refillTable1.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
  <include file="refillTable2.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
  <include file="refillTable3.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
  ...
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The issue is that they have **constraints** on each other so I cannot drop everything from `Table3` without dropping everything from `Table1` beforehand, therefore when I need to refill `Table3` with `refillTable3.sql` I need `refillTable1.sql` to be reexecuted too.

How can I make all three scripts reexecute when I change only one on them? I explicitly don't want to reexecute all scripts on every deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the "include" tag, I'd use the "sql" tag and put it in a changeSet.

Then, you can add "runOnChange=true" to the "changeSet" tag. The changeSet will be executed when the .sql file is updated.

```
<changeSet runOnChange="true" id="1" author="r2">
    <sqlFile path="refillTable1.sql"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet runOnChange="true" id="2" author="r2">
    <sqlFile path="refillTable2.sql"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet runOnChange="true" id="3" author="r2">
    <sqlFile path="refillTable3.sql"/>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Thank you @Robert, do you mean <changeset>< sqlFile../>< sqlFile../>< sqlFile../></changeset>?

Comment: You want each sqlFile tag in to own changeSet so they will run when changed. If you put them all in one they will ALL run if one is changed. That's what you wanted, right. Run only ones that changed?

Comment: I want to run ALL when one changed. Will try in a couple of hours.